# Reading and representing input which specifies the data type to use

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I'd like to read some data which itself specifies the data type to use.

For example, let's assume there may be user inputs like these:

```
integer pair 1 2
integer triple 1 2 3
real pair 1 2
real triple 1 2 3
```

and there is a data type to represent it:

```
data (MValue a) => T a = TP (Pair a) | TT (Triple a)
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Pair a = Pair a a deriving (Show, Eq)
data Triple a = Triple a a a deriving (Show, Eq)
```

where the allowed value types have to belong to `MValue` class:

```
class (Num a, Read a) => MValue a where
  typename :: a -> String
  readval  :: [String] -> Maybe a

instance MValue Int where
  typename _ = "integer"
  readval [s] = maybeRead s
  readval _   = Nothing

instance MValue Double where
  typename _ = "real"
  readval [s] = maybeRead s
  readval _   = Nothing

maybeRead s =
  case reads s of
    [(x,_)] -> Just x
    _       -> Nothing
```

I can easily write readers for `Pair`s and `Triple`s:

```
readPair (w1:w2:[]) = Pair <$> maybeRead w1 <*> maybeRead w2
readTriple (w1:w2:w3:[]) = Triple <$> maybeRead w1 <*> maybeRead w2 <*> maybeRead w3
```

The problem is *how do I write a polymorphic reader for the entire `T a` type*?:

```
readT :: (MValue a, Read a) => String -> Maybe (T a)
```

I want:

1. The type `a` is chosen by the caller.
2. `readT` should produce `Nothing` if the user's input is incompatible with `a`.
3. `readT` should produce `Just (T a)` if the input is valid.
4. Numbers should be read as integers or as doubles depending on the input.

A naive implementation

```
readT :: (MValue a, Read a) => String -> Maybe (T a)
readT s =
  case words s of
    (tp:frm:rest) ->
        if tp /= typename (undefined :: a)
           then Nothing
           else case frm of
             "pair" -> TP <$> readPair rest
             "triple" -> TT <$> readTriple rest
             _ -> Nothing
    _ -> Nothing
```

gives an error in the line `if tp /= typename (undefined :: a)`:

```
rd.hs:45:17:
    Ambiguous type variable `a' in the constraint:
      `MValue a' arising from a use of `typename' at rd.hs:45:17-41
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

The error goes away if I remove this check, but how can I verify if the user input is compatible with the data type chosen by the caller? A solution might be to have separate `readTInt` and `readTDouble`, but I'd like the same `readT` to work polymorphically the same way as `read` does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `a` in `undefined :: a` is not the same `a` as the ones in `readT`'s signature.  There is a language extension available in GHC that enables that, called "ScopedTypeVariables".  A more portable fix would be to introduce a little extra code to explicitly tie the types together, for example:

```
readT :: (MValue a, Read a) => String -> Maybe (T a)
readT s = result
  where
    result = 
      case words s of
        (tp:frm:rest) ->
            if tp /= typename ((const :: a -> Maybe (T a) -> a) undefined result)
               then Nothing
               else case frm of
                 "pair" -> TP <$> readPair rest
                 "triple" -> TT <$> readTriple rest
                 _ -> Nothing
        _ -> Nothing
```

This is a very quick and dirty modification of your code, and I'm the changes could be made more elegantly, but that should work.

Comment: Thank you. This works. The trick with `result` as an argument to undefined `Maybe (T a) -> a` is unexpected.

Comment: Actually, `result` and `undefined` are both arguments to `const :: a -> Maybe (T a) -> a`, which forces their types to be related in the way given by the explicit type signature on `const`.  But yea, `(undefined :: Maybe (T a) -> a) result` would work too.