# How to reuse a type variable in an inner type declaration

Tags: haskell

As part of my Haskell learning process, I like to explicitly type out the type declarations for functions. I would like to be able to do so for functions defined in a where clause, but I don't know how to specify, that a type variable in a where clause should denote the same type as some type variable in the outer type declaration. For instance, the following code:

```
foo :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
foo f arg = bar arg
  where
    bar :: a -> a
    bar a = f a
```

yields this error:

```
src\Test.hs:7:14:
    Couldn't match expected type `a' against inferred type `a1'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `foo' at src\Test.hs:3:8
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for `bar' at src\Test.hs:6:11
    In the first argument of `f', namely `a'
    In the expression: f a
    In the definition of `bar': bar a = f a
```

How can I express that the first argument to bar should be of the same type as the second argument to foo, so that I can apply f to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you can do this in general with [ScopedTypeVariables](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/scoped_type_variables.html) which GHC supports.  This certainly compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
foo :: forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a
foo f arg = bar arg
  where
    bar :: a -> a
    bar a = f a
```

Note the "forall a."

Answer (score 8):

There is another workaround. Instead of referencing `f` within the inner function `bar`, extend `bar` to accept `f` as a first argument and use partial application in the parent.

```
foo :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
foo f arg = (bar f) arg
  where
    bar :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
    bar f a = f a
```

It does not require ScopedTypeVariables or explicit type checking code as the other answers.

#### Explanation

For clarity let's change the type parameter in `bar` to `b` and also rename its argument.

```
foo :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
foo f arg = bar arg
  where
    bar :: b -> b
    bar x = f x
```

Haskell complains because `bar` is annotated as `b -> b` (for any arbitrary type  `b`), but `f x` is attempting to apply an argument of type `b` to a function of type `a -> a` (for a specific, bound `a`). In other words, the inner function is not as general as its type annotation advertises.

Passing `f` to `bar` means that for the expression `(bar f)`, the type variable `b` is bound to the same type as `a`.

#### Even simpler

And finally, without changing anything else, if you're willing to omit the type signature for the inner function `bar`, Haskell will infer its type exactly the way you want. That is, since `bar` applies `f` from from the parent function `foo`, the type of `bar` will reuse the type parameter `a` from the type of `foo`.

```
foo :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
foo f arg = bar arg
  where
    -- Type: bar :: a -> a
    bar a = f a
```

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174187/reading-and-representing-input-which-specifies-the-data-type-to-use/4174266#4174266) to another question shows a trick to use if you do not want to use ScopedTypeVariables extension.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scoped_type_variables

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables