# In Haskell, how do I force an expression to be of the return type of the function?

Tags: haskell, types, integer, polymorphism

I want to generalize this function to be `(Integral a, Integral b, Bounded b) => a -> [b]` but I don't know how to force `maxBound` to have the type of the result. Is this possible?

```
go :: Integral a => a -> Maybe (Word8, a)
go 0 = Nothing
go x 
    | x < 0 = error "Negative numbers are not acceptable"
    | otherwise = Just $ (remainder, quotient)
    where
        quotient = fromInteger $ (toInteger x) `div` (toInteger (maxBound :: Word8))
        remainder = fromInteger $ (toInteger x) `mod` (toInteger (maxBound :: Word8))

int2WordList :: Integral a => a -> [Word8]
int2WordList x = unfoldr go x
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reuse a type variable in an inner type declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476378/how-to-reuse-a-type-variable-in-an-inner-type-declaration)

Comment: also, look into using `divMod` to get `quotient` and `remainder` at the same time.

Comment: `divMod` gives you quotient and remainder of the same type. I need different types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you want to use a type parameter at some point in your function. That's exactly what [scoped type variables](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scoped_type_variables) are for:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Word
import Data.List

go :: forall a b. (Integral a, Integral b, Bounded b) => a -> Maybe (b, a)
go 0 = Nothing
go x 
    | x < 0 = error "Negative numbers are not acceptable"
    | otherwise = Just $ (remainder, quotient)
    where
        quotient  = fromInteger $ (toInteger x) `div` (toInteger (maxBound :: b))
        remainder = fromInteger $ (toInteger x) `mod` (toInteger (maxBound :: b))
    --                                                                        ^
    --                                               that's the same `b` as above   

int2List :: (Integral a, Integral b, Bounded b) => a -> [b]
int2List x = unfoldr go x
```

Alternatively you can use `asTypeOf`:

```
go :: (Integral a, Integral b, Bounded b) => a -> Maybe (b, a)
go 0 = Nothing
go x 
    | x < 0 = error "Negative numbers are not acceptable"
    | otherwise = Just $ (remainder, quotient)
    where
        quotient  = fromInteger $ (toInteger x) `div` (toInteger (maxBound `asTypeOf` remainder))
        remainder = fromInteger $ (toInteger x) `mod` (toInteger (maxBound `asTypeOf` remainder))

int2List :: (Integral a, Integral b, Bounded b) => a -> [b]
int2List x = unfoldr go x
```

`asTypeOf` is a rather simple function, but its type makes sure that `remainder` and `maxBound` have the same type:

```
asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a
asTypeOf = const
```

Answer (score 3):

The Haskell 98 solution to this problem is the [`asTypeOf`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=asTypeOf) function, e.g.:

```
quotient  = fromInteger $ (toInteger x) `div` (toInteger (maxBound `asTypeOf` remainder))
```

I would suggest re-working your expressions a bit, though:

```
xInt = toInteger x
mbound = toInteger (maxBound `asTypeOf` remainder)
quotient = fromInteger $ xInt `div` mbound
remainder = fromInteger $ xInt `div` mbound
```

which will make it a bit clearer that you want to divide `x` by the same value but then round the result to two different types.